# google AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() always return null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Here's my code.

`var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();`

I already tried other suggestions like updating the packages but no luck.

Comment: what is the problem?
can you explain more about that?

Comment: you can share your code snippets, error logs, any useful information to help other members to find your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you checking for an error message sent by the external login provider?
Here is how I am doing it using an ExternalLoginCallback action in my account controller:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string remoteError = null)
{
    if (remoteError != null)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, $"Error from external provider: {remoteError}");
        return View("Login", loginUser);
    }
    var loginInfo = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
    
    (rest of code...)
}
```

Comment: From Browser, what does data to send to this ExternalLoginCallback ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by updating all my owin packages.

Thank you